# Parse new RSS items when published with older pubDate

Tags: php, xml-parsing, rss

I am parsing RSS feeds with the following procedure:

1. The parser runs once, fetches all the RSS items and stores the time run;
2. Then every time it runs again it checks if an RSS item has a later
   `pubDate` than the last time run and stores it in the database.

My problem is that for a specific website's feed, some items are added after the last ones but with the same `pubDate`, so my parser doesn't store them.

For example at 9pm it has one item with `<pubDate>Fri, 01 Mar 2013 05:00:00 Z</pubDate>`
and later at 12pm it adds another with the same `pubDate`.

The feed does not offer a `guid`.

Is there any way to get the actual latest items?

Here the code that i am using now

```
function getLatest($lastTimeRun, $data, $pubDates)
{
    $latestData = array();
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
    {
        $pubDates[$i] = strtotime($pubDates[$i]);
        //compare the last time the script run with each feed's item publish date                
        if($lastTimeRun < $pubDates[$i])
        {
            array_push($latestData, $data[$i]);
        }
    }

    return $latestData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply compare the titles of the last x after the last publishdate to find any new entries, also match the other data to see if it *is* really a new entry. Then just limit the last xx entries you are looking for.